# Excel INDIRECT to ignore errors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-indirect

I am looking for a way to make an INDIRECT formula ignore errors and print a 0 instead. I have it working in a round about way but would like it neater.

I have an `INDIRECT` formula to load a cell from a seperate worksheet

```
=INDIRECT("'Invoice (2)'!A1")
```

The reason I've used an `INDIRECT` is so that when the sheet named 'Invoice (2)' is not available (i.e. I've temporarily deleted it) it does not change my formula.

However. When there is NO 'Invoice (2)' sheet, I get the error: `#REF!`
What I would prefer is the result to be '0'.

I have a work around by hiding this field and then referencing it in an `AGGREGATE` field
`=AGGREGATE(9,6,N19)` - The 6 ignores any errors and puts a '0' in place and this works perfectly.

So I guess I am just curious if there is a way to combine the two as to make it neater. You would think there would be an 'ignore error' for other commands other than aggregate.

I have tried `=AGGREGATE(9,6,INDIRECT("'Invoice (2)'!A1"))` and the script finds the data fine but it does not ignore errors like it should.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your formula with the [IFERROR](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/iferror-function-HA001231765.aspx) function thus:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'Invoice (2)'!A1"),0)
```

Comment: thank you very much :) This worked a treat. So much more elegant than my approach. Google was not my friend on this occasion.